# If / Else / Switch returning the wrong results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I'm making a Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock (Big Bang Theory, the tv show) using ReactJS and i'm facing some kind of abstract issue.

```
switch (this.state.playerOnePick === 'Rock') {
    case((this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Scissors') || (this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Lizard')):
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Player One wins !</h1>
            <h2>P1: {this.state.playerOnePick} P2: {this.state.playerTwoPick}</h2>
        </div>
    );
        break;
    case((this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Paper') || (this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Spock')):
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Player Two wins !</h1>
                <h2>P1: {this.state.playerOnePick}
                    P2: {this.state.playerTwoPick}</h2>
            </div>
        );
        break;

}

switch (this.state.playerOnePick === 'Lizard') {
    case((this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Spock') || (this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Paper')):
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Player One wins !</h1>
                <h2>P1: {this.state.playerOnePick} P2: {this.state.playerTwoPick}</h2>
            </div>

        );
        break;
    case((this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Scissors') || (this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Rock')):
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Player Two wins !</h1>
                <h2>P1: {this.state.playerOnePick} P2: {this.state.playerTwoPick}</h2>
            </div>
        );
        break;

}
```

Rock vs Paper is returning the right results, no matter who's picking it, when P1: Rock, P2: Lizard, P1 wins as expected, but when P1: Lizard P2: Rock, it is returning that P1 wins..

[What it returns me when P1:Lizard P2:Rock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80As0.png)

There is nowhere where Lizard is supposed to win vs Rock...

(playerOnePick and playerTwoPick are correctly updated as the player pick a weapon)

Comment: Well, that's what you're setting on lines 22 and 23. According to [this](https://cdn.instructables.com/FIU/AIWE/I7Q0TCUT/FIUAIWEI7Q0TCUT.MEDIUM.jpg), your rules are correct.

Comment: player two wins, because you've set this way. take a look at what `<h1>` says in last `case` statement.

Comment: `switch (this.state.playerOnePick === 'Rock')`  makes no sense. You're matching a boolean there. Sounds like what you really want is plain `if`/`else`.

Comment: Well player 2 SOULD win but it's returning me that player 1 wins, actually..

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage of `switch` statements would be

```
switch (this.state.playerOnePick) {
    case 'Rock':
        switch (this.state.playerTwoPick) {
            case 'Scissors'):
            case 'Lizard':
                return "Player One wins!";
                break; // unnecessary after `return` but well
            case 'Paper':
            case 'Spock':
                return "Player Two wins!";
                break; // as above
        }
        break;
    case 'Lizard':
        switch (this.state.playerTwoPick) {
            case 'Spock':
            case 'Paper':
                return "Player One wins!"
            case 'Scissors':
            case 'Rock':
                return "Player Two wins!";
        }
        break;
}
```

What you have shown is the layout for `if`/`else`, with lots of boolean conditions:

```
if (this.state.playerOnePick === 'Rock') {
    if ((this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Scissors') || (this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Lizard')) {
        return "Player One wins!";
    } else if ((this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Paper') || (this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Spock')) {
        return "Player Two wins!";
    }
} else if (this.state.playerOnePick === 'Lizard') {
    if ((this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Spock') || (this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Paper')) {
        return "Player One wins!";
    } else if ((this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Scissors') || (this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Rock')) {
        return "Player Two wins!";
    }
}
```

However, the real issue with implementing Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock is all that duplication (which leaves a lot room for error). The actual programming task is to figure out how to reduce that.
Tip: Assign each possible pick an integer number, and play around with some maths.
Write a separate function `winner(pick1, pick2)` that returns `-1` when the first player wins, `0` for a tie, and `1` when the second player wins. Then simply call that from the ReactJS code that is concerned with the UI stuff.

Comment: Alright it works well like that ! I'll try my best to save some repetitions and with the maths, i rarely use switch statement, i'm not particularly familiar with it, thank you so much !

Comment: Sounded fun so I made an implementation. Look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/zZvypp). The idea is to write the rules as array. Then one of the player is used as the key of the object, array filter to check if player 2 has lost and a simple ternary operation to return the winner.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, no problem. The `switch` statement is nothing you'll miss in usual programming. Just go for nested if/elses, and when that is not enough, go right for a lookup table (e.g. `Map`).

Comment: @SumiStraessle Yes, that `win_rules` thing looks perfect. Of course, you could squeeze out a bit more efficiency and genericy with more maths, but only at the expense of readability.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback !  I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Switch case does not work like that. If you want to use switch case, you'd do something like:

```
switch(playerOnePick) {
 case 'Rock':
   switch(playerTwoPick) {
    case 'Scissors':
    case 'Lizard':
      // Player 1 wins
      break;
    case 'Paper':
    case 'Spock':
    // Player 2 wins
    break;
   }
   break;
 case 'Lizard':
   switch(playerTwoPick) {
    case 'Spock':
    case 'Paper': 
      // Player 1 wins
     break;
    case 'Scissors':
    case 'Rock': 
    // Player 2 wins
    break;
 }
}
```

etc.

Edit: Your code written like that is constructed for if statements, if you replace the switch and case with if, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you've set it that way. look at last`<h1>`.

Say, you could write a better `switch/case` statement to evaluate the condition. You are highly repeating yourself which is against *DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself)* principal.

You can pull `<h2>P1: {this.state.playerOnePick} P2: {this.state.playerTwoPick}</h2>` completely out of `switch` block & place it immediately after switch's closing `}`. Or you'd better put only one single value per case instead of combining couple of them under one case. It makes it much harder to follow the code. This is my choice for this particular switch-case:

```
switch (this.state.playerOnePick === 'Rock') {
    case(this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Scissors'):
         return ( <div> <h1>Player One wins !</h1> </div>);
         break;
    case(this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Lizard')):
         return ( <div> <h1>Player One wins !</h1> </div>);
         break;
    case(this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Paper'):
         return ( <div> <h1>Player Two wins !</h1> </div>);          
         break;
    case(this.state.playerTwoPick === 'Spock'):
         return ( <div> <h1>Player Twi wins !</h1> </div>);        
         break;
    }
// The same goes for second switch
<div><h2>P1: {this.state.playerOnePick} P2:{this.state.playerTwoPick}</h2><div>
```