# Game counter for a JavaScript Rock Paper Scissors Game is not working

Tags: javascript, function, dom, while-loop

I have created a Rock Paper Scissors game that plays 5 rounds in the console and am now trying to refactor it to work in a browser with buttons using DOM manipulation.

The button and round functions are:

```
rock_btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
round('rock');
})

paper_btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
round('paper');
})

scissors_btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
round('scissors');
})


function round (playerSelection) {
let computerSelection = computerPlay();
if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
        playerScore++
        userScore_span.innerHTML = playerScore;
        result_div.innerHTML = 'You Win\! Rock beats Scissors\!';
    } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
        computerScore++;
        compScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
        result_div.innerHTML = 'You Lose\! Rock beats Scissors\!';
    } else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
        playerScore++;
        userScore_span.innerHTML = playerScore;
        result_div.innerHTML ='You Win\! Paper beats Rock\!';
    } else if(playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        computerScore++;
        compScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
        result_div.innerHTML = 'You Lose\! Paper beats Rock\!';
    } else if(playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        playerScore++;
        userScore_span.innerHTML = playerScore;
        result_div.innerHTML ='You Win\! Scissors beats Paper\!';
    } else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
        computerScore++;
        compScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
        result_div.innerHTML = 'You Lose\! Scissors beats Paper\!';
    } else {
        result_div.innerHTML = ('A draw! Please play again!');
    }
}
```

the game function used to count the rounds worked when called in the console but now has no effect:

```
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function game () {
while (playerScore <= 5 || computerScore <= 5) {
round();
if(playerScore === 5) {
    result_div.innerHTML = 'Player Wins!!!';
}
if(computerScore === 5) {
    result_div.innerHTML = 'Computer Wins!!!';
    }
    }
}
```

Could someone please advise me how I can insert the game function into the sequence so the counter works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Since you're relying on the game being played with buttons on your DOM, you should check for the win condition at the end of our `round` function:

Win condition:

```
function win_condition () {
  if(playerScore === 5) {
    result_div.innerHTML = 'Player Wins!!!';
  }
  if(computerScore === 5) {
    result_div.innerHTML = 'Computer Wins!!!';
  }
}
```

in your `round` function:

```
...

else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
        computerScore++;
        compScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
        result_div.innerHTML = 'You Lose\! Scissors beats Paper\!';
    } else {
        result_div.innerHTML = ('A draw! Please play again!');
    }

  win_condition();
}
```

You could refactor a bit of your code by [DRYing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it up, maybe abstract the rules away (i.e. rocks win against scissor but loses against paper, etc.)
I did something like this on another post. [See this CodePen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/zdjarG):

- lines 66 to 79 define the win conditions;
- lines 93 to 99 how it's used.

Mind you, it's in [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), so you'd need to apply it a bit differently, but the principle stays: abstract the logic away and DRY up your code.

(BTW: global mutable state will bite you eventually, you'd improve your code a lot by [making your functions pure](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch03.html))

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: See [the other Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520994/if-else-switch-returning-the-wrong-results#42521183) I was referencing.

Comment: Thank you, I had been thinking about switch statements to be honest, but I was more concerned with just getting the thing working first! Agree very much on the DRYing, I am a bit new to this though, are there any articles or resources you can recommend on this just to provide a decent framework of reference?

Comment: That's great: KISS approach first (i.e. *make it work*), then optimization. [Early optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) is an antipattern.

Comment: I would try to use more functions in your example first, then try to make them pure (i.e. everything you use has to be passed as argument to say it quickly, but you should read the [Mostly Adequate book](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/) I've referenced). The [Do Factory book on design pattern in javascript](http://www.dofactory.com/products/javascript-jquery-design-pattern-framework) was a good read too. I would also go through [Angular's tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) which is a modern JS framework, and also try ReactJS, another modern front-end framework.

Comment: There are course for ReactJS on [CodeSchool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/powering-up-with-react) and [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/react-redux-react-router-es6), amongst others.

Comment: Will do! Cheers